# GameplayKit > Scene Editor Navigation Graph > How to use it for pathfinding?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, path-finding, gameplay-kit

Not long ago, Apple introduced GameplayKit elements to Xcode's Scene Editor, which is great. However, I seem to have issues with the Navigation Graph element:
[image: Scene Editor Navigation Graph]

What I try to achieve is to draw a GKGraph from the Scene Editor, retrieve it in code, and use it as a base for pathfinding.

So I draw a GKGraph first:

[image: Scene Editor drawn GKGraph]

Then I retrieve it in GameScene.swift like this:

```
graph = self.graphs.values.first
```

where *graphs* is a predefined array by Apple to store the GKGraphs from the Scene Editor. So far so good.

Then I want for the player to find the path to the tap location on screen. For this, I use *UITapGestureRecognizer* with the following callback method:

```
var moving = false
func moveToLocation(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    var tapLocation = recognizer.location(in: recognizer.view!)
    tapLocation = self.convertPoint(fromView: tapLocation)

    guard (!moving) else { return }
    moving = true

    let startNode = GKGraphNode2D(point: vector_float2(Float(player.visualComponent.node.position.x), Float(player.visualComponent.node.position.y)))
    let endNode = GKGraphNode2D(point: vector_float2(Float(tapLocation.x), Float(tapLocation.y)))

    NSLog(graph.nodes.debugDescription)

    graph.connectToLowestCostNode(node: startNode, bidirectional: true)
    graph.connectToLowestCostNode(node: endNode, bidirectional: true)

    NSLog(graph.nodes.debugDescription)

    let path: [GKGraphNode] = graph.findPath(from: startNode, to: endNode)
    guard path.count > 0 else { moving = false; return }

    var actions = [SKAction]()

    for node: GKGraphNode in path {
        if let point2d = node as? GKGraphNode2D {
            let point = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(point2d.position.x), y: CGFloat(point2d.position.y))
            let action = SKAction.move(to: point, duration: 1.0)
            actions.append(action)
        }
    }

    graph.remove([startNode, endNode])

    // Convert those actions into a sequence action, then run it on the player node.
    let sequence = SKAction.sequence(actions)
    player.visualComponent.node.run(sequence, completion: { () -> Void in
        // When the action completes, allow the player to move again.
        self.moving = false
    })
}
```

Using this method, I get the player to go to the tap location. The problem is that the path returned by GameplayKit only includes the *startNode* and the *endNode*, meaning that the player does not walk on the the pre-drawn GKGraph at all but walks straight to the *endNode*.

Note: When I'm first running *NSLog(graph.nodes.debugDescription)* it lists all 10 pre-drawn nodes. When I'm then running it again after *graph.connectToLowestCostNode*, I get all 12 nodes. So my graph seems to contain everything needed for pathfinding.

What do you think is the problem? Why is *graph.findPath* not using the pre-drawn 10 nodes to define the path? Your answers would be much appreciated.

Comment: how can  get that graph object in my swift code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like GameplayKit's *.findPath* method does not work properly when called on a GKGraph created from Scene Editor. What I did is, I cloned the nodes from the pre-drawn GKGraph to a programmatically created GKGraph:

```
let newGraph = GKGraph()
for drawnNode in graph.nodes! {
    newGraph.add([drawnNode])
}
```

Then, *.findPath* on it works just fine:

```
newGraph.connectToLowestCostNode(node: startNode, bidirectional: true)
newGraph.connectToLowestCostNode(node: endNode, bidirectional: true)
let path: [GKGraphNode] = newGraph.findPath(from: startNode, to: endNode)
```

Variable `path` contains now a path generated considering all 10 + 2 nodes.

**Wrap-up:** You cannot directly use a Navigation Graph created in Scene Editor for pathfinding. My solution was to first clone its nodes to a programmatically created GKGraph and then use the latest to do the rest.